# Tomcat Freezes deploying SpringBoot App

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, watchservice

I'm trying to deply some Apps (4 spring boot web apps) in Tomcat 9 , I noticed 2 of them make Tomcat log to display:

```
17-Nov-2016 00:15:07.110 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11/webapps/ftpoutbound990-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

And it stays that way just deploying it doesn't display DEPLOYMENT FINISHED.
the thing is that the App WORKS even when it doens't appear DEPLOYED completely.
(I see my log4j entries and files are processed in the monitored folder)

These apps monitor 2 different folders using Java watchService with the following code:

package com.ftpoutbound990.monitor;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ftpoutbound990.client.FtpoutboundApp;

@Component
public class MonitorDirectory {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MonitorDirectory.class);

    @Autowired
    private FtpoutboundApp ftpoutboundapp;

    @Value("${folder990}")
    private String folder990;

    public void startMonitoring() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("INICIO DE MONITOREO DE ARCHIVOS 990");
        try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {

            Path faxFolder = Paths.get(folder990);

            WatchService watchmyservice = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            faxFolder.register(watchmyservice, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

            boolean valid = true;
            do {
                try {
                    WatchKey watchKey = watchmyservice.take();

                    for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                        WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                            String fileName = event.context().toString();
                            logger.info("ARCHIVO NUEVO:" + fileName);
                            boolean isGrowing = false;
                            Long initialWeight = new Long(0);
                            Long finalWeight = new Long(0);
                            Path child = faxFolder.resolve(folder990 + fileName);
                            do {
                                initialWeight = child.toFile().length();
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                finalWeight = child.toFile().length();
                                isGrowing = initialWeight < finalWeight;
                                logger.info("AUN COPIANDO ARCHIVO:" + fileName);
                            } while (isGrowing);
                            logger.info("LISTO ARCHIVO:" + fileName);
                            getFile(fileName);
                        }
                    }
                    valid = watchKey.reset();
                    // Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ClosedWatchServiceException e) {
                    //watchmyservice.close();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

            } while (valid);
        }
    }

    public void getFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(folder990 + fileName);
        ftpoutboundapp.createGateway(file);
    }

}
```

If I remove the Do-While the Apps do finished deployed! But why? It's a standard Java watchservice code, could anybody help me to realize what I'm missing/what's the issue?
the thing is that Tomcat doesn't deploy my 4th App cause it keeps deploying the 3rd one.
Thanks in advance for your help

---

EDIT 1: ADDING THREAD

```
28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.559 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.613 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.664 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:404)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:407)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1344)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.904 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.907 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 6 2016 18:54:10 UTC
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.9.5
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_73-b02
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11/conf/logging.properties
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11/temp
28-Dec-2016 18:00:21.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/viruskimera/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.063 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.093 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.096 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.098 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.100 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 604 ms
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.145 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.145 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11
28-Dec-2016 18:00:22.224 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Users/viruskimera/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M11/webapps/ftpoutbound990-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
28-Dec-2016 18:00:26.346 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a shot in the blind..

A simple review of your code suggests that if an exception is thrown inside the try catch, the boolean flag `valid` remains `true` causing an infinite loop.

Hence set the flag to false in the body of the `catch` block!

Comment: I'm checking this.

Answer (score 2):

The tomcat deployer thread seems invoking the `startMonitoring` method. As intended, this method never returning back and hence deployment is not getting complete.

To fix this, need to run the monitoring method in separate (or background) thread.

Below refactored example may be helpful.

Aside note, a single instance of WatcherService instances can be used for watching the multiple directories.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MonitorDirectory {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MonitorDirectory.class);

    @Autowired
    private FtpoutboundApp ftpoutboundapp;

    @Value("${folder990}")
    private String folder990;

    private WatchService watchService;

    private ExecutorService eventLoop = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        eventLoop.submit((Runnable) () -> {
            try {
                startMonitoring();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("ERROR...", e);
            }
        });
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() throws IOException {
        eventLoop.shutdownNow();
        if (watchService != null) {
            watchService.close();
        }
    }

    public void startMonitoring() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("INICIO DE MONITOREO DE ARCHIVOS 990");
        Path faxFolder = Paths.get(folder990);
        WatchKey watchKey = faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(kind)) {
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    logger.info("ARCHIVO NUEVO:" + fileName);
                    boolean isGrowing = false;
                    Long initialWeight = new Long(0);
                    Long finalWeight = new Long(0);
                    Path child = faxFolder.resolve(folder990 + fileName);
                    do {
                        initialWeight = child.toFile().length();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        finalWeight = child.toFile().length();
                        isGrowing = initialWeight < finalWeight;
                        logger.info("AUN COPIANDO ARCHIVO:" + fileName);
                    } while (isGrowing);
                    logger.info("LISTO ARCHIVO:" + fileName);

                    getFile(fileName);
                }
                valid = watchKey.reset();
            }
        } while (valid);
    }

    public void getFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(folder990 + fileName);
        ftpoutboundapp.createGateway(file);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying this

Comment: look at my EDIT 1, this is a local run, but I'm afraid it will be the same in the server. I applied your code and freezes the same then I shutdown tomcat and displays: look at line SEVERE ERROR: 28-Dec-2016 17:57:27.664, it says error awaiting deployment to be completed. I even tried changing spring version from v1.4.1.RELEASE to v1.3.6.RELEASE since 1 app using v1.4.1.RELEASE deploys correctly but the same happens.

Comment: BTW I noticed the memory consumption of the java process increases.

Comment: I am assuming you `startMonitoring is getting called from background thread only. Also it looks a bit strange that timeout exception is getting while stopping tomcat server(can you try after adding Thread.interrupted()  condition in while condition. E.g. while( valid && !Thread.interrupted()).

Comment: looks same, notice the app always runs even the deployment is not finished, cause the apps shows start monitoring message in log4j file but after that tomcat freezes (it doesn't deploy more apps)

Comment: this only runs in 1 pc, we have copied tomcat, jdk, everything... But not yet sure why is not running in the server...

Comment: looks like a configuration issue but still not sure what... if this is not solved I will use SCHEduled task to monitor the folder (last option...)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the few things below.

Is the Component MonitorDirectory is called only once in your applications.  If not, you may need to declare 'eventLoop' as static and check the initialization in PostConstruct to avoid multiple initialization and invocation.

Also, executorservice is initialized with the threadpool of 1 and if Multiple MonitorDirectory object is initialized in your application, this might lead to the deployment freeze

Is there any chance, the filesize could be shrinking in the server environment. This might lead to infinite looping on 'isGrowing' check..

Comment: Part of that code was suggested by user Skadya above but I would say MOnitor is called only 1 time, how could monitor be called more than once? Notice this runs 1 pc but we have copied everything from that PC (jdk, tomcat, etc.) I tried using @scheduled annotation, seems working but still dealing with some issues.

Comment: In Spring, whenever an object is initialized the 'postConstruct' method will be invoked. If the Application can produce multiple objects for the same object (typical web application with concurrency) this can happen..